# 3 power supplies in parallel

Tags: power

I have 3 power supplies all of which are stack-able.

- Powermax PM3-100
- 2× SUPERNIGHT 12V 30A

Do they have to be identical to stack? I can adjust the voltage but would like to get 160amps if possible out of the 3.

Comment: What does the manual say about stacking the supplies?

Comment: 30A * 3 = 90A << 160A, unless I'm missing something. How do you propose to get 160A by stacking?

Comment: The only way to get a real answer is from the manufacturer.  At a minimum, this question requires links to the datasheets of the supplies in question.  Without specific information to the contrary for particular supplies, you have to assume power supplies can not be connected in parallel.

Comment: This also raises the question what the heck do you need 80A * 13.8V = 1.1kW (2.5kW peak!) amplifier for? You're tired of the sounds of the world?

Answer (score 7):

There is no indication from the manufacturer that those power supplies are "stackable" in any sense of the word. Unless you know what you are doing and take extraordinary measures, you can safely assume that those power supplies can NOT be "stacked" or connected in parallel to provide higher current.  If you have a reference to your "stackable" source information, it would be an excellent idea to cite it explicitly.

Comment: SOME power supplies are DESIGNED to be paralleled (or "stacked"). So that they will "cooperate" with each other instead of fighting with each other.  But unless your power supply was designed to be paralleled, or you provide some external means of current-balancing, you should assume that power supplies, and especially switching supplies) cannot be safely paralleled.  Are there cases where people get lucky or accidentally create current-balancing circuitts?  Sure. But that is not a general-case answer, and you could kill yourself and burn down your house relying on luck for high-power design.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I'd stack those power supplies is on top of each other and even in that case they're pretty darn high power so even that may be a recipe for a disaster.

Since you let us finally know the application is an amplifier with a 80A base load, I'd just use one 100A PSU and get a 2F car audio capacitor.

**edit** On 2nd thought that 2 farad capacitor will only hold up for about 10ms before voltage drops by 1V with 180A load. Not quite enough for that 50Hz bass drum. 8 farad cap would hold for four cycles or 80ms that may or may not be enough.

Answer (score -1):

If your power supply has voltage and current limit, it may very well be possible to stack them directly. The loop stability inside each power supply may be unhappy about it but most of the time it will work fine.

If you only have voltage control, or fixed voltage and OCP or similar, you will have a much harder time to stack them. If you measure the maximum voltage difference and connect a resistor in series for each supply that drops just over the maximum voltage difference at the maximum current and have a diode in series for each, you may get away with it, but regulation would suffer and you will have losses in the (OR-)diodes.

Answer (score -3):

They are able to be put in parallel with no issues. The PM3-100 is 100 amps the other 2 are 30 amps each.

Also, I've been running the 2 30a power supplies in parallel for over a year now at 13.8v. Now I have a class C / S amp that will continuously draw 80 amps and peak at 180a which is why I want to add the 100a power supply. I just picked up another PM3-100 so I am going to end up running 2 of them in parallel to get 200a at 13.8v.

---

So far no issues. Here are examples, not mine, but similar. My amp could draw upwards of 180amps at 2550 watts.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYEiXy_ToT0&feature=youtu.be
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9eceKkJ3gVo

In the car audio world many times contests for sound quality and SPL take place indoors. Running your car indoors is dangerous obviously because of carbon monoxide. Power supplies provide a way to power up your gear without having to run your engine.

Comment: The fact that you appear to have it working in one instance is not proof of the general case.  Your setup could easily have a bit more resistance (or something else) in certain places that allows these particular supplies in your case to be stable.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I wouldn't worry so much about stability as I'd be concerned about current distribution. Also depending on the PSU you may be tripping overload protection constantly.

Comment: Contacted the manufacturer that builds the Pm3-100's and they said no issues with running in parallel. Just fyi. Been running with no issues now. No thanks to you who have contributed negatively